# Roslyn Add a document to a project

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm running roslyn ctp2

I am attempting to add a new html file to a project

```
IWorkspace workspace = Workspace.LoadSolution("MySolution.sln");
var originalSolution = workspace.CurrentSolution;
ISolution newSolution = originalSolution;
newSolution.GetProject(newSolution.ProjectIds.First())
                        .AddDocument("index.html", "<html></html>");
workspace.ApplyChanges(originalSolution, newSolution);
```

This results in no changes being written. I am trying to get the new html file to appear in VS

Comment: Most objects in Roslyn are immutable, so I think you need to use the project that is returned by `AddDocument()`. But I'm not sure how to do it, without removing the old project and then adding the new one back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. Roslyn `ISolution`, `IProject`, and `IDocument` objects are immutable, so in order to see changes you would need to create a new `ISolution` with the changes, then call `Workspace.ApplyChanges()`.
2. In Roslyn, `IDocument` objects are only created for files that are passed to the compiler.  Another way of saying this is things that are part of the `Compile` `ItemGroup` in the project file.  For other files (including html files), you should use the normal Visual Studio interfaces like `IVsSolution`.

Answer (score 5):

Workspaces are immutable. That means that any method that sounds like it's going to *modify* the workspace will instead be returning a *new* instance with the changes applied.

So you want something like:

```
IWorkspace workspace = Workspace.LoadSolution("MySolution.sln");
var originalSolution = workspace.CurrentSolution;
var project = originalSolution.GetProject(originalSolution.ProjectIds.First());
IDocument doc = project.AddDocument("index.html", "<html></html>");
workspace.ApplyChanges(originalSolution, doc.Project.Solution);
```

However, I'm not near a machine with Roslyn installed at the moment, so I can't guarantee this 100%.

Comment: Its not the workspaces that are immutable, but just about everything else. The workspace itself mutates, firing events when it changes.  The solution, project and document objects are immutable and they exist in a hierarchy.  When you change a project by adding a document you get a new project instance back that is a member of a new solution instance.  You need to use the new solution instance when you apply the changes back to the workspace or you wont see the changes in the workspace.